# Why does it go from Alien vs. Predator to Aliens vs. Predator?

Tags: alien-franchise, predator-series, alien-vs.-predator, alien-vs.-predator-requiem

The first film in the mini-franchise that is AVP is titled *Alien vs. Predator*. The sequel to it is titled *Aliens vs. Predator: Requiem*. Simply, why did the sequel add an "s" to the Alien part? Why not add on to the Predator part? There were multiple aliens and multiple predators in the first film, so there's no reason why the first one wouldn't have that title.

Comment: One Predator, many Xenomorphs?

Comment: “Snakes...on Every Plane!”

Comment: because that's what the first 2 alien films were called. Alien, Aliens

Comment: @DavidW Except there were many aliens AND many predators in the first film.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino Only in the prologue to the _actual_ story.  The bit that people paid to see had 1 Predator hunting down the Predalien queen and her offspring.

Comment: I can't say why, but the film had a working title of 'Alien Vs Predator 2' and was at one point going to be called 'Alien Vs Predator: Survival of The Fittest'. Both of which were Alien in the singular. https://whatculture.com/film/predator-gets-double-teamed-in-aliens-vs-predator